# Open front and top panels on Whirlpool Cabrio gas dryer

Tags: dryer

I have a Whirlpool Cabrio gas dryer, model WGD8200YW2, that started making some squealing noises. I bought a [parts kit](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B0053F8D1U/) to do a little tune up. I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove the front panel, though. All of the videos I found on youtube are either for dryers with the lint trap on top (this model has it inside the door) or with a split front panel (this model has a single full-height front panel).

I was able to remove the back plate and replace the idler pulley, and I can see the drum support rollers, but can't access them easily to replace. I also can't thread the belt back onto the drum without getting into the front and/or top. How is the front (and top for that matter) supposed to come off on this dryer?

Edit: I've got a [parts diagram](http://www.whirlpool.com/digitalassets/MLPDF/Repair%20Part%20List%20-%20W10520420.pdf). I can see the locating tab (#35) and lock (#43) at the top front, but I'm not seeing a way to release them. I can slide a putty knife in behind the lock and push one side of forward, but that leaves the front portion still. I can't seem to push the front portion back at all.

Comment: Most of the dryers I have worked on l had to pull up the top  then there were several screws maybe 2 or 3 on each side had to removed, then the front panel could be pulled forward the drum pulled and the idlers removed and replaced. Hope this helps.

Comment: @EdBeal That's typical of what I saw on youtube videos, too, but doesn't seem to be how this dryer comes apart. The top seems to be hinged, but there's some kind of locking tab at the front. See my edit with a parts diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Is this correct](http://www.whirlpool.com/-%5BWGD8200YW%5D-1020611/WGD8200YW/)
I am almost certain that is the same model I have if so I have opened mine a year or so back.  I installed the LP gas conversion and reversed the door.
I will search my archives and see if I can find how I opened up the front.  I know it was found when I searched by looking for installing LP conversion.  The link shows door change in the pdfs but not much more.

Something in back of my head tells me I had to pop the top up to lift the face.  And I am fairly sure I removed a couple of screws.   Again I will search my old computer archives for info I saved on this (a few terra bites of files to look through).  But do look at videos on LP conversion for more light on subject.

[Install instruction video](http://www.appliancepartspros.com/whirlpool-lp-gas-conversion-w10606694a-ap5781887.html#autoplay)

Comment: That's the same model. I'll look for info on lp conversion

Comment: I just verify it is the same model I have, again now if I can just find where I put my files for it.

Comment: I found this video: http://www.appliancepartspros.com/whirlpool-lp-gas-conversion-w10606694a-ap5781887.html#autoplay, which shows the clips being released using a putty knife from the front. I'll try tonight...

Comment: Yes sir that is it.  That is where I bought my LP kit from also.  I remember lifting the top, pulling the connector and then the nut driver screws were so annoying.  Dropped one putting back together and had to fish it out.

Comment: Oh and getting the top to set back down was a bit fun.